# Application of some estimate to stopped process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I have question regarding this step:

Assume you have a stochastic process $X_t$ and a stopping time $\tau$.

Furthermore assume that some estimate like

$\mathbb{E}f(X_t)\leq \mathbb{E}g(X_t)$ holds for some suitable functions $f,g$.

Can I simply conclude that also

$\mathbb{E}f(X_t^\tau)\leq \mathbb{E}g(X_t^\tau)$

holds, where $X^\tau$ is the stopped process.

Comment: $\tau$ = first time $f(X_t)>g(X_t)+1$

Comment: Not in general: take a simple random walk on $\mathbb Z$ starting at the origin and $f(x)=x^3, g(x)=x$. Then both $Ef(X_t)=Eg(X_t)=0$. Now stop at the first moment $t$ when $X_t=3$, say. Then $X_t^\tau=3$ with probability $1$ but $3^3>3$.

Comment: Thank you for both nice examples.